# Update uipopover height when cell is added

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a table view (without scrolling) inside a UIPopoverController which has 4 cells.  And sometimes it needs to have an extra cell (1 max).  If I am animating the adding and subtracting of that cell, can I update the popover's height as well?

Here is how I create the popover table view:

```
- (void)createPopoverTable
{

    //set up array
    _arrayList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];


    //Make row selections persist.
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;


    //View height
    NSInteger rowsCount = [_arrayList count];
    NSInteger singleRowHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    NSInteger totalRowsHeight = (rowsCount * singleRowHeight) + 20;

    //View width
    CGFloat largestLabelWidth = 0;
    for (NSString *item in _arrayList) {
        //check size of font using default label
        CGSize labelSize = [item sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
        if (labelSize.width > largestLabelWidth) {
            largestLabelWidth = labelSize.width;
        }
    }

    //some padding for the width
    CGFloat popoverWidth = largestLabelWidth + 200;

    //Tell popover the size
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverWidth, totalRowsHeight);
}
```

Then in one of my methods I have this code for when the table needs to change:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

//update the array
[_arrayList insertObject:@"Blue" atIndex:3];

//insert the row
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The code all "works" fine but when I add the extra cell, it is being cut off due to the non scrolling nature of my popover controller.  Any way I can update that?

Comment: why you want to update height of UIPopOverView ?? even UITableView has already scrollView so tableView adjust it self. :)

Comment: I have scrolling disabled, it just fits better with the overall app.  I need to change the height because part of my last cell is being cut off and without scrolling it looks terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one it worked for me

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.tableView.contentSize;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.popoverControllerContainer setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something different but this put me in the right direction.